# Is it illegal to modify a cookie to become a chat admin?

Tags: networking, security

I doubt it is, but I found a site where you can modify a cookie to become admin, is this legally okay?
Thanks

Comment: Not only is it not legally OK more importantly (in my opinion) it's not morally OK either. And for some belief systems, your morality dictates what happens to you for eternity (you don't want to be re-incarnated as toejam, for example) and is probably far more important than the legality of the question.

Comment: You are morally obligated to report it to the site owner (and possibly also to thedailywtf.com).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, No it isn't legally okay.

Although that may change depending on what part of the world you are in. As a general rule of thumb, any access you gain that wasn't given to you (no matter how easy to obtain) would be classified as illegal.

Comment: Do you think authorities would care?

Comment: Whether or not the authorities care is a moot point. It's still illegal. If I kill a homless man, and nobody ever even knows he's missing, let alone trace it to me, is that OK?

Comment: What I mean is, do you think they would go through the trouble of tracing my ip just for this?

Comment: If you arent supposed to be an admin, then its wrong.  So why do it?

Comment: If someone fucked around with admin rights on my network you're damn straight I would track down their IP and send an infringement notice to their ISP with the IP Address, Date and time of the infringement. And this works, because in a previous life I used to pull stunts like that and my ISP sent me a cease-and-desist notice after they got complaints that they tracked to my IP.